# "Git commit" takes a very long time (> 40 seconds) to open vim. What could be happening?

Tags: vim, git

When I run `git commit -m 'some commit message'`, everything works as expected. When I run vim on its own, everything works as expected. Yet when I run `git commit`, which launches vim, it takes up to 40 seconds for vim to load. What could be happening here? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12216578/584121) I was able to profile my setup, and found that the plugin `github-issues` was causing long slowdowns. I disabled the plugin and everything is now fine.

Comment: I know it has been a long time, but I have the same problem and can't figure out, how I would use the given answer to help with a slow start-up. (vim works fine once it's open) I would greatly appreciate some help. (The --startuptime doesn't help either, because it is only slow for git commit)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/899626/git-commit-takes-a-very-long-time-40-seconds-to-open-vim-what-could-be-ha#comment1961794_899712), it is difficult (or I think impossible) to understand how to utilize [the answer posted by the OP](https://superuser.com/a/899712/1091982).

Use this instead:

```bsh
GIT_TRACE=1 git commit
```

This `GIT_TRACE=1` enables verbose output of any Git commands. In my case, it turned out `git log` in `prepare-commit-msg` hook had taken around 5 seconds as the commit history was long.

Ref: [*How can I debug git/git-shell related problems?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17344517/8776746)